# Mindstorms EV3 brick does not play sound file to the end

Tags: mindstorms

I have a 16 seconds WAV file and am trying to play it. It plays only the first 8 seconds both on the brick and on the Mindstorms programming software.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like EV3 supports sound files up to maximum 8 seconds. You can split the files with sound editor and play one after each other.